# Can I associate one class with another from a template (using C++17 variant)?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, variant, visitor-pattern

I have some code that accepts one type of object and creates another type of object based on the type of the first. (There is a 1->1 relationship between the types.) I originally used a hash table (`unordered_map<>`) with a key based on the type of the first object to associate a creation function for the second object. But as I am learning more about the C++ features introduced since the last time I was full-time C++, I discovered `std::variant<>`.
I have successfully converted the implementation to use this C++17 feature. However, there is one remaining piece that is still a bit cumbersome. The design makes a call to a static member function of the second class to validate the contents of the first object, before instantiating an object of the second class. To handle this right now, I'm using a visitor structure with function operators overloaded for each input type.
What I'm wondering is if there is some way to use a template for the association, rather than the copied code with only the types different?
I've tried looking at the way `std::variant<>` works, and I see where the index of the type can be obtained with `.index()`. I can see how to instantiate an object based on an index, which I might use if I created a second `std::variant<>` with the object types. But, as you can see, I don't want to instantiate the object until the parameters have been validated. The function that does that is static, and I don't see a way to associate the parms type with the object type in a way that lets me make the static call.
(I also realize that these two visitor structures can be combined in the code below, but in the real code, the creation is longer and more complicated, and I would rather not have copies of it in each overload.)

```
struct Type1Parms {};
struct Type2Parms {};
struct Type3Parms {};
...

struct TypeBase {};
struct Type1 : public TypeBase
{
    static bool ValidateParms(const Type1Parms&);
    Type1(const Type1Parms&);
};
struct Type2 : public TypeBase
{
    static bool ValidateParms(const Type2Parms&);
    Type2(const Type2Parms&);
};
struct Type3 : public TypeBase
{
    static bool ValidateParms(const Type3Parms&);
    Type3(const Type3Parms&);
};
...

struct ValidateParmsVisitor
{
    bool operator()(const Type1Parms& parms)
    {
        return Type1::ValidateParms(parms);
    }
    bool operator()(const Type2Parms& parms)
    {
        return Type2::ValidateParms(parms);
    }
    bool operator()(const Type3Parms& parms)
    {
        return Type3::ValidateParms(parms);
    }
...
};

using TypeParms = std::variant<Type1Parms, Type2Parms, Type3Parms, ...>;

struct CreateObjectVisitor
{
    std::unique_ptr<TypeBase> operator()(const Type1Parms& parms)
    {
        return std::make_unique<Type1>(parms);
    }
    std::unique_ptr<TypeBase> operator()(const Type2Parms& parms)
    {
        return std::make_unique<Type2>(parms);
    }
    std::unique_ptr<TypeBase> operator()(const Type3Parms& parms)
    {
        return std::make_unique<Type3>(parms);
    }
...
};

template<typename TParms>
std::unique_ptr<TypeBase> CreateType(const TParms& parms)
{
    unique_ptr<TypeBase> obj;
    if (visit(ValidateParmsVisitor{}, parms))
        obj = visit(CreateObjectVisitor{}, parms);
    return std::move(obj);
}
```

Is there a way to make this association, especially as a type that can be used with a static member function call?
EDIT: I should explain that this is part of a much larger project, with a number of other design criteria that shape its design.
For example, this is for a client interface, where the API is meant to be as simple as can be expressed. The client only has visibility (via header) to the parms structures and a function that takes the parms & returns an object that contains the objects mentioned above. The original design did indeed have a base structure for the parms, which obviously had to be in the public header. However, this meant that a client could inherit from the base class themselves and pass this into the object creation function, or inherit from the acceptable structures. To avoid segfaults, this necessitated adding runtime checks to be sure the types were acceptable, which was mostly handled by the hash design--although it wasn't quite that simple. When I removed the hash design, I also lost this method of type validation, but I recognized that this would be replaced by a compile time check with the `variant<>`, handling custom structures (no base to check now). I also learned about the C++ version of the `final` keyword which handled the inheritance issue.
Additionally, while the code above does not show it, the parms structures contain multiple members and the `ValidateParms()` functions actually attempt to validate whether the values and combinations are valid.

Comment: `I also realize that these two visitor structures can be combined in the code below, but in the real code, the creation is longer and more complicated, and I would rather not have copies of it in each overload.`
could you move the validate into the creation visitor but make the return value of creation either be an optional variant or add a null value to the created object variant?

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned (and you quoted), the function that calls validate and create has more code, including between the two calls. This is a simplified example to make the question more clear.

Comment: yeah just seems to me like it would be easier to move the common creation code into a function or something than it would be to do type traits etc. but it depends on the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create traits for the association:

```
template <typename T> struct from_param;

template <> struct from_param<Type1Parms> { using type = Type1; };
template <> struct from_param<Type2Parms> { using type = Type2; };
template <> struct from_param<Type3Parms> { using type = Type3; };
```

Then, you might do

```
using TypeParms = std::variant<Type1Parms, Type2Parms, Type3Parms>;

std::unique_ptr<TypeBase> CreateType(const TypeParms& parms)
{
    if (std::visit([](const auto& param){
            return from_param<std::decay_t<decltype(param)>>::type::ValidateParms(parms);
        }, parms))
    {
        return std::visit([](const auto& param) -> std::unique_ptr<TypeBase> {
            return std::make_unique<typename from_param<std::decay_t<decltype(param)>>::type>(parms);
        }, parms);
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41c11070a2c291e9)

or without variant, if you call with correct type:

```
template <typename T>
auto CreateType(const T& parms)
{
    if (from_param<T>::type::ValidateParms(parms))
    {
        return std::make_unique<typename from_param<T>::type>(parms);
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: This is very much what I had hoped to see (thank you!). But I'm having trouble getting this to compile. First, had to add capture of parms to lambdas. Now getting error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct from_param<const Type1Parms&>’. (I tried ...from_param<const Type1Parms>..., but that didn't help.) I'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: As mentioned, this is a bit more complicated in the actual code. There are a couple of `variant<>`s in use, 1 has only 1 type for now. But the same errors occur for `variant<>`s with more types.

Clearly the compiler is failing to use the specialized template. I tried changing the argument type of the lambda: `visit([&parms](auto p){ return from_param`..., and it did appear to use the specialization, but the error changed to: `no matching function for call to ‘Type1::ValidateParms(const variant<Type1Parms>&)’` with a `note: candidate: static bool Type1::ValidateParms(const Type1Parms&)`.

Comment: Can you provide MCVE on coliru or godbold or any other online compiler?

Comment: I've been working with the full source code as I made the change from hash (`unordered_map<>`) to `variant<>`, and I put your code there as well. But to get a better look and/or share, I'm going to have to distill this down to a stand-alone app. The compiler we have to use is 7.3.0, so I'm wondering if this might be a compiler issue. Otherwise, it's a short between keyboard and ground. B-|

Comment: I've distilled this down & was surprised that the problem remains in newer compilers. The starting place is https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebe350ef54925d3b. As mentioned above, to see if I could help the compiler use the specialized templates, I modified lines 131 & 137 to remove the const & reference, which changed the error. The distilled error is different (cannot convert vs. no matching function), but still shows the inability to convert from the `variant<>` to one of its types. I've tried some other things, but nothing that has led me to an solution.

Comment: Version fixed and demo added.

Comment: Outstanding @Jarod42. This worked in the sample & the actual code. Now I'm going to have to learn about decay.

Comment: [std::decay](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) basically removes reference and const.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple method, a set of overloaded functions:

```
unique_ptr<TypeBase> CreateType(Type1Params const& params)
{
    return make_unique<Type1>(params);
}
unique_ptr<TypeBase> CreateType(Type2Params const& params)
{
    return make_unique<Type2>(params);
}
unique_ptr<TypeBase> CreateType(Type3Params const& params)
{
    return make_unique<Type3>(params);
}
```

Notes:

- You can add another overload to catch other parameters and then return null, but I think a compile-time error would be preferable.
- You could also use a template function and specializations, but there's probably little typing to safe that way.